# How to stop chain method calls?

Tags: java, android, function, chaining, chain

I have code in which there are number of functions are executing one by one e.g.

```
void a(){
   //do some stuff
   b();
}
void b(){
   // do something
   c();
}
void c(){
   // do something
}
```

now at given time I want to stop this chain irrespective to which function is in execution right now. I have stop this chain processs at given time. how can do it in android(java)?

Comment: What's your plan? What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: describe your actual use case. that would give a proper picture of the requirement.

Comment: the use case is there is one process is ongoing in background which has this kind of chain method calls if user presses back I have to cancel the ongoing operation. @SagarNayak

Comment: Background means using Async task or some other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by this way

```
boolean stop = false;

void a(){
    //do some stuff
    if(!stop)
    b();
}
void b(){
    // do something
    if(!stop)
    c();
}
void c(){
    // do something
    if(!stop){

    }
}


void stopCallingMethod(){
    stop = true;
}
```

if you want to stop the methods a, b, c you can call stopCallingMethod() method